React Native Expo yearly scheduled notifications working but not showing
`Hi guys i have a problem about expo-notifications .
I am creating a reminder app and i need scheduled notifications.I created scheduled notification function and that's main work about triggers.Yearly notification added but not showing the notification . This is my schedulenotification function and js page :`
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import * as Calendar from "expo-calendar";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { saveToLocalNotification } from "../services/NotificationService";
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: true,
  }),
});


export const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
      name: "default",
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
    });
  }


  const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync({
    projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
  });
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;

  if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync({
      projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
    });
    finalStatus = status;
  }

  if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
    alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
    return;
  }

  const token = (
    await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
      projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
    })
  ).data;
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(`pushToken`, JSON.stringify(token));
  return token;
};


export const **scheduleNotificationAsync **= async (
  type,
  date,
  content,
  data = null
) => {
  try {
    if (!(date instanceof Date) || isNaN(date)) {
      throw new Error("Invalid date parameter");
    }

    const targetDate = new Date(date);
    const now = new Date();
    let trigger = {};

    const getTimeDiffInSeconds = (target, current) =>
      (target.getTime() - current.getTime()) / 1000;

    switch (type) {
      case "D":
        trigger = {
          hour: targetDate.getHours(),
          minute: targetDate.getMinutes(),
          repeats: true,
        };
        break;

      case "W":
        trigger = {
          weekday: targetDate.getDay(),
          hour: targetDate.getHours(),
          minute: targetDate.getMinutes(),
          repeats: true,
        };
        break;

      case "M":
        trigger = {
          day: targetDate.getDate(),
          hour: targetDate.getHours(),
          minute: targetDate.getMinutes(),
          repeats: true,
        };
        break;

      case "Y":
        trigger = {
          month: targetDate.getMonth() + 1,
          day: targetDate.getDate(),
          hour: targetDate.getHours(),
          minute: targetDate.getMinutes(),
          repeats: true,
        };
        break;

      case "N":
        trigger = {
          seconds: getTimeDiffInSeconds(targetDate, now),
          repeats: false,
        };
        break;
      default:
        trigger = {
          seconds: getTimeDiffInSeconds(targetDate, now),
          repeats: false,
        };
        break;
    }

    const notificationId = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: {
        ...content,
        data: data,
      },
      trigger,
    });

    return notificationId;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to schedule notification:", error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error to handle it at the call site if needed
  }
};


Also expo go not showing yearly btw
